# Monitoring JBOSS ESB

Tags: jboss, monitoring, hyperic, jboss-esb

Can anyone suggest which monitoring tool is the best for monitoring JBOSS, in particular ESB queue depth etc?

I currently use Hyperic with a custom plugin, does anything support JBOSS ESB out of the box?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JBoss Operations Network is your best bet if you want an out-of-the-box working project.

http://www.jboss.com/products/jbosson/

Comment: Looks good for JBOSS specifics.  Looks well worth a trial run.  Thanks for responding.